# Using this forum - help please

Tags: support

Hi,

I am new to this forum, and it is very good, but the struture is unusual in having comments and answers.

Can anyone tell me how I can see any/all new or last answers or new or last comments?

I find it very difficult to hunt them down

Comment: 1. Have you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)? 2. It's not too clear what you are asking here, please try to clarify.

Comment: @Benjol: I'm afraid OP won't figure out what "migrated to meta.SO" means, it's a bit hard in the beginning...

Answer (score 2):

You can click on "newest" to see the answers sorted by date, and comments are sorted by date automatically. But each answer has its own comments, so you have to check them all.

You can click on the star next to a question to mark it as favourite, then you'll automatically get notified of all new answers and comments by a lit up envelope icon next to your user name.